# How can I set up userpool's preferred_username as sign in option via Amplify CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I am using Amplify CLI to create formation stack for Cognito Userpool.

After `amplify add auth`I go through a setup process where one of the options is:

```
How do you want users to be able to sign in? Username
```

However, after `amplify push` and checking userpool in AWS Console I see more options:

[image]

Additionally to username I can choose "Sign in with email", "Sign in with verified phone number", "Sign in with preferred username"

How these options can be chosen via Amplify CLI?